# Count number of values across multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, pivot, unpivot

I have a table with 11 columns. The first column includes the category names. The remaining 10 columns have values like white, green, big, damaged etc. and these values can change in time.

I need a SQL query to find how many are there in table (in 10 columns) each value.

**Table 1:**

```
+------------+------------+
|  ID        | decription |
+------------+------------+
| 1          | white      |
| 2          | green      |
| 3          | big        |
| 4          | damaged    |
+------------+------------+
```

**Table 2:**

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  CATEGORY  | SECTION 1 | SECTION 2 | SECTION 3 |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Category 1 | white     | green     | big       |
| Category 2 | big       | damaged   | white     |
| Category 1 | white     | green     | big       |
| Category 3 | big       | damaged   | white     |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Desired result:

```
+------------+-------+-------+-----+---------+
|  CATEGORY  | White | Green | Big | Damaged |
+------------+-------+-------+-----+---------+
| Category 1 |    20 |    10 |   9 |      50 |
| Category 2 |    25 |    21 |  15 |       5 |
+------------+-------+-------+-----+---------+
```

Is it possible doing like this dynamically just as query ?

its on MS sql in visual studio reporting

Thanks

Comment: You chose a bad table design. Can you change it?

Comment: With "rows" you mean columns, right?

Comment: please fix the title so it makes some sense

Comment: you are right juergen d but i can't change it :( sorry Thorsten Kettner, you are right, i ment column. changing now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got yourself a bit of a mess with the design and the desired result.  The problem is that your table is denormalized and then the final result you want is also denormalized. You can get the final result by unpivoting your `Section` columns, then pivoting the values of those columns. You further add to the mess by needing to do this dynamically.

First, I'd advise you to rethink your table structure because this is far too messy to maintain.

In the meantime, before you even think about writing a dynamic version to get the result you have to get the logic correct via a static or hard-coded query.  Now, you didn't state which version of SQL Server you are using but you first need to unpivot the `Section` columns. You can use either the UNPIVOT function or CROSS APPLY.  Your query will start with something similar to the following:

```
select 
  category,
  value
from yourtable 
unpivot
(
  value for cols in (Section1,Section2,Section3)
) u
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14a12/4). This gets your data into the format:

```
|   CATEGORY |   VALUE |
|------------|---------|
| Category 1 |   white |
| Category 1 |   green |
| Category 1 |     big |
| Category 2 |     big |
| Category 2 | damaged |
| Category 2 |   white |
```

Now you have multiple `Category` rows - one for each value that previously were in the `Section` columns.  Since you want a total count of each word in the `Category`, you can now apply the pivot function:

```
select 
  category,
  white, green, big, damaged
from
(
  select 
    category,
    value
  from yourtable 
  unpivot
  (
    value for cols in (Section1,Section2,Section3)
  ) u
) un
pivot
(
  count(value)
  for value in (white, green, big, damaged)
) p;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14a12/5).  This will give you the result that you want but now you need this to be done dynamically.  You'll have to use dynamic SQL which will create a SQL string that will be executed giving you the final result.

If the number of columns to UNPIVOT is limited, then you will create a list of the new column values in a string and then execute it similar to:

```
DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot as  NVARCHAR(MAX);


select @colsPivot 
        = STUFF((SELECT ',' + quotename(SectionValue)
                 from yourtable
                 cross apply
                 (
                   select Section1 union all
                   select Section2 union all
                   select Section3
                 ) d (SectionValue)                
                 group by SectionValue
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query 
  = 'select category, '+@colspivot+'
      from
      (
        select 
          category,
          value
        from yourtable 
        unpivot
        (
          value
          for cols in (Section1, Section2, Section3)
        ) un
      ) x
      pivot
      (
        count(value)
        for value in ('+ @colspivot +')
      ) p'

exec sp_executesql @query
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14a12/10)

If you have an unknown number of columns to unpivot, then your process will be a bit more complicated. You'll need to generate a string with the columns to unpivot, you can use the `sys.columns` table to get this list:

```
select @colsUnpivot 
    = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
             from sys.columns as C
             where C.object_id = object_id('yourtable') and
                   C.name like 'Section%'
             for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Then you'll need to get a list of the new column values - but since these are dynamic we will need to generate this list with a bit of work.  You'll need to unpivot the table to generate the list of values into a temporary table for use. Create a temp table to store the values:

```
create table #Category_Section
(
    Category varchar(50),
    SectionValue varchar(50)
);
```

Load the temp table with the data that you need to unpivot:

```
set @unpivotquery 
  = 'select 
        category,
        value
      from yourtable 
      unpivot
      (
        value for cols in ('+ @colsUnpivot +')
      ) u'

insert into #Category_Section exec(@unpivotquery);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14a12/7). You'll see that your data looks the same as the static version above. Now you need to create a string with the values from the temp table that will be used in the final query:

```
select @colsPivot 
        = STUFF((SELECT ',' + quotename(SectionValue)
                 from #Category_Section
                 group by SectionValue
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
```

Once you have all this you can put it together into a final query:

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot as  NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @unpivotquery  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @colsUnpivot 
    = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
             from sys.columns as C
             where C.object_id = object_id('yourtable') and
                   C.name like 'Section%'
             for xml path('')), 1, 1, '');

create table #Category_Section
(
    Category varchar(50),
    SectionValue varchar(50)
);

set @unpivotquery 
  = 'select 
        category,
        value
      from yourtable 
      unpivot
      (
        value for cols in ('+ @colsUnpivot +')
      ) u';

insert into #Category_Section exec(@unpivotquery);

select @colsPivot 
        = STUFF((SELECT ',' + quotename(SectionValue)
                 from #Category_Section
                 group by SectionValue
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query 
  = 'select category, '+@colspivot+'
      from
      (
        select 
          category,
          value
        from yourtable 
        unpivot
        (
          value
          for cols in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
        ) un
      ) x
      pivot
      (
        count(value)
        for value in ('+ @colspivot +')
      ) p'

exec sp_executesql @query
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14a12/8). All versions will get you the end result:

```
|   CATEGORY | BIG | DAMAGED | GREEN | WHITE |
|------------|-----|---------|-------|-------|
| Category 1 |   2 |       0 |     2 |     2 |
| Category 2 |   1 |       1 |     0 |     1 |
| Category 3 |   1 |       1 |     0 |     1 |
```

If your values are stored in a separate table, then you would generate your list of values from that table:

```
DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot as  NVARCHAR(MAX);


select @colsPivot 
        = STUFF((SELECT ',' + quotename(decription)
                 from descriptions             
                 group by decription
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query 
  = 'select category, '+@colspivot+'
      from
      (
        select 
          category,
          value
        from yourtable 
        unpivot
        (
          value
          for cols in (Section1, Section2, Section3)
        ) un
      ) x
      pivot
      (
        count(value)
        for value in ('+ @colspivot +')
      ) p'

exec sp_executesql @query
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1cf7/1) and still get the same result:

```
|   CATEGORY | BIG | DAMAGED | GREEN | WHITE |
|------------|-----|---------|-------|-------|
| Category 1 |   2 |       0 |     2 |     2 |
| Category 2 |   1 |       1 |     0 |     1 |
| Category 3 |   1 |       1 |     0 |     1 |
```

Comment: i know table design is messy but this is what i could do :(
i edited the question. one another table includes the decriptions (white, big etc. and in time will be additions). visual studio reporting...

Comment: @güven See my edit, you'd just get your values to be pivoted by querying the separate table.

Comment: thank you @bluefeet, you solved my problem on sql management studio. i hope it works also in vs report query editor.

Comment: hello @bluefeet, is there a way to make this query as View?

Comment: @güven dynamic sql has to be done in a stored procedure not a view.

Comment: I asked it a couple of unseccessful attempt to report (rdlc) creation with stored procedure. Than I thought maybe i can use  view but... thanks for your help @bluefeet

Answer (score 1):

```
select category,
       SUM(CASE when section1='white' then 1 when section2='white' then 1 when section3='white' then 1 else 0 end) as white,
       SUM(CASE when section1='green' then 1 when section2='green' then 1 when section3='green' then 1 else 0 end) as green,
       SUM(CASE when section1='damaged' then 1 when section2='damaged' then 1 when section3='damaged' then 1 else 0 end) as damaged,
       SUM(CASE when section1='big' then 1 when section2='big' then 1 when section3='big' then 1 else 0 end) as big
from test
group by category
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c17f/1)

You can extend more to n section values as shown above gor section1,section2,section3

Comment: Thank you mmhasannn, your solution is half useful for me but i need smt more. values (green, big, etc.) stored in another table and they can change/increase in time. is there a way to add new walues into the query dinamically?